# What to do with static method overrides?

Tags: java, oop

For example,

```
public class A {
    public static int f() { return 1; }
}

public class B extends A {
    public static long f() { return 100L; }
}
```

Unfortunately `B.f()` couldn't be compiled because `B.f()` tries to override `A.f()`, and so the name clashes because the return types aren't compatible.

I'm weired what's purpose to override a static method? Any use case? Can I just hide away `A.f()` in class B?

**Actual usage:**

```
class EntityDTO {

    public static List<EntityDTO> marshal(Collection<? extends Entity> entities) {
        ...
    }

}

class BookDTO extends EntityDTO {

    public static List<BookDTO> marshal(Collection<? extends Book> books) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to rename the methods to marshalEntity and marshalBook. Or maybe BookDTO should not extend EntityDTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static methods are not overriden...But it is called method hiding. The benefits of using the same method name and parameters are just like any other method overriding benefits

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, static methods can not be overridden. Method overriding is exclusively a feature of object polymorphism, and static methods doesn't belong to any object but the class itself.

Having clarified that, you should not make any of your methods `static`. That would solve your problem in hand, at least. As the method arguments are different, it will not be considered as overriding, but overloading.

Answer (score 1):

static method can not be overridden.

Notice: your `B.f()` should return int rather than long to pass compile.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a use case where overriding static functions (in Java) can be useful, but if you ever absolutely must achieve it, here's how:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class A {

    public static void callOut() {

        System.out.println("A.callOut");
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    public static void callOut() {

        System.out.println("B.callOut");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        A a = new A();
        A b = new B();

        Method aM = a.getClass().getMethod("callOut");
        Method bM = b.getClass().getMethod("callOut");

        aM.invoke(null); // prints A.callOut
        bM.invoke(null); // prints B.callOut
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point you are making. Using reflection for this just overkill. You achieve exactly the same by doing `A.callOut(); B.callOut();`.

Comment: Actually the point is when I unbind & invoke the methods, I do not know (or care) for their classes. Imagine having an array with A & B instances and looping over it:A[] ary = new A[100]; /* fill array up */; for (A a : ary) { a.getClass().getMethod("callOut").invoke(null); }; would correctly call the specific callOut method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to rethink you design, if you have a need to override the marshal method, then it shouldn't be static in the first place.

Comment: There are non-static `marshal()`s which do the real marshal. The static one is a helper function to marshal collections.

Comment: IMHO, static methods are always invoked with the class, rather then  the instance, so why bother with overrides?

Comment: I totally missed your compilation issue, though you are right that a static method is accessed through class, a sub-class also has access to static methods of parent class, they can either be hidden or overloaded by the sub-class. In your example you gave since the method signature(parameters) is same for both cases its neither hiding nor overloading, thus the error message.